# How to replace Microsoft Word Review Features with shared plaintext documents

Tags: version-control, plaintext

I prefer to work with plaintext documents for documentation and reports, composed in markdown or LaTeX. However, I have to share my work and this requires that I convert documents to Word (or, **shudder**, PowerPoint). The main functions used by the community of Word users are the collaborative Review features; the ability to track changes, accept or reject them, add comments etc. I'd like to try to persuade my community to switch to plaintext and markdown, which I realize will be a challenge.

My question is, what is a good workflow to replace Word/Review in a plaintext environment. I have searched and found serval options which wouldn't quite work for my community. The requirements are

1. It must be simple.
2. It must work on both Windows and OS X.
3. It cannot be a web based solution as the content will be proprietary (unless we can run it from our own internal secure server, but this would be not ideal.)
4. It cannot have too high a learning curve.

Many of my colleagues are familiar with version control for software and I am assuming a solution involving git or svn could be an option, but haven't found a good description of a workflow that would work.

If you do this, what tools do you use and what is your workflow?

Comment: http://criticmarkup.com seems to be one solution, if not a mature one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Version control for software does not differ fundamentally from version control for just text
2. *Some* frontend will be usable addition, from my POV (while not mandatory, yes)
3. Mercurial (or TortoiseHG as GUI) can work on both OS (powered with internal HGLab instance or not), can be linked to (internal again) ReviewBoard

Possible workflows:

- Clean "central" repo with documents, forks for edits and (approved|rejected) Pull Requests
- Pure-DVCS mode with MQ. Suggested edits are MQ-patches, transferred to reviwers with MQCollab extensions. Rejected pathches just deleted, approved - converted to changesets